# Bash increment alphanumeric data from command prompt

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I need to increment alphanumeric data.

Increment numbers with `seq` is easy just: `seq -w 0000001 9999999 >> file`

But I need to increment alphanumeric data in order like this:

```
0000001
0000002
0000003
0000004
0000005
0000006
0000007
0000008
0000009
000000a
000000b
000000c
000000d
000000e
0000010
0000011
0000012
0000013
0000014
0000015
0000016
0000017
0000018
0000019
000001a
000001b
000001c
000001d
000001e
0000020
0000021
```

etc... until I hit eeeeeee

Using alphanumeric data `{0-9a-e}`. Just need to load the data in an empty file and done. Is there an easy bash command for this something similar to the `seq` command? I'm using Linux Debian 6.3.0-18 and Bourne Again Shell.

Comment: These are numeric data in hex. They are not arbitrary alphanumeric data.

Comment: I don't see any f in there: are you sure that it should not be there? That would be base 15 numeric data which seems ... strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really mean hex (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F) here is a solution up to FF (I don't want to have to count to 4.3 billion):

```
(echo obase=16; seq 1 $((echo ibase=16; echo FF) | bc)) | bc
```

The inner

```
(echo ibase=16; echo FF) | bc
```

calculates the ending value in decimal (here FF but feel free to substitute FFFFFFFF if you want :-). The `seq` then counts from one to 255 in this case, and the rest converts it to hex.

And if you really want base 15, you can change both 16's to 15's (and the FF... to EE...).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. How can I make it start at 0000001 instead of 1?

Comment: You could pipe that command into `| xargs printf "%7s\n" | tr ' ' 0`

Answer (score 1):

Just play with the print operators

```
#!/bin/bash
 for number in $( seq 1 255 )
  do
    hex_representation=$( printf "%X" ${number} )
    echo "${number}: ${hex_representation}"
 done
```

Comment: Or just `printf '%06X\n' $(seq 1 255)` (I added zero padding in line with the OP's desired output format)

Comment: This answer is also a good solution. In the loop how can I control the output? In the loop 0000001 is sent to an empty file like this: printf '%06X\n' $(seq 1 255) > file. Then on second loop cycle 0000002 is sent into the file, etc. Is there a simple way to pause this command until next loop?